# Data sharing in GUI, Matlab

Tags: user-interface, matlab

now I'm developing a GUI with pop-up windows, so actually it is a workpackage with multiple GUIs.

I have read thorough the examples given in help files (changme, and toolpalette), but I failed to animate the method to transfer data from the new one back to the old one.

Here is my problem.

I have two GUIs, A, the Main one and B that I use it to collect input data and I want to transfer the data back to B.

### Question 1:

I want to define new subclasses of handles in A.
lets say,
`handles.newclass`
how can I define its properties, e.g. 'Strings'?

### Question 2:

In A, a button has the callback

`B('A', handles.A);`

so we activate B.fig.

After finished the work in B,
it has collected the following data (string and double) in B(!)

```
title_1 itle_2 ... title_n
```

and

```
num_1 num_2 ... num_n
```

I want to pass the data back to A.

Following the instruction, I wrote the codes shown below.

```
    mainHandles = guidata(A);
title = mainHandles.title_1;
set(title,'String',title_1);
```

However, when I go back to A, handles in A was not changed at all.

Please someon help me out here.

Thank you!

=============update================

The solution I found is adding extra variables (say handles.GUIdata) to handles structure of one GUI, and whenever the data are required, just read them from the corresponding GUI.
And It works well for me, since I have a main control panel and several sub-GUIs.

Comment: can't you just use the return values from the function of the second GUI when called from the first

Comment: "Sharing Data Among a GUI's Callbacks" http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f13-998449.html and http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8525-nested-functions-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

There is a short discussion of this issue [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/254977).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But since I only use these data once (actually there the directories for the real input data), so I want to avoid from using global

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues where I wanted external batch scripts to actually control my GUI applications, but there is no reason two GUI's would not be able to do the same.

I created a Singleton object, and when the GUI application starts up it gets the reference to the Singleton controller and sets the appropriate gui handles into the object for later use. Once the Singleton has the handles it can use set and get functions to provide or exchange data to any gui control that it has the handle for. Any function/callback in the system can get the handle to the singleton and then invoke routines on that Singleton that will allow data to be exchanged or even control operations to be run. Your GUI A can, for instance, ask the controller for the value in GUI B's field X, or even modify that value directly if desired. Its very flexible.

In your case be sure to invalidate any handles if GUI A or B go away, and test if that gui component actually exists before getting or modifying any values. The Singleton object will even survive across multiple invocations of your app, as long as Matlab itself is left running, so be sure to clean up on exit if you don't want stale information laying around.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24911-design-pattern-singleton-creational

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Question 2, it looks like you forgot to first specify that Figure `A` should be active when setting the title. Fix that and everything else looks good (at least, the small snippets you've posted).